# Degree of parametrization of $\textrm{SO}_n$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G=\mathrm{SO}_{2 n}$ (or $G=\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}$, $G=\mathrm{Sp}_{2 n}$ …) defined over some field $K$. Consider $G$ as an affine subvariety of the space of matrices.

1. (Warm-up question) What are the asymptotics of $\deg(G)$?
   There's [Brandt, Bruce, Brysiewicz, Krone, and Robeva - The degree of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03200) (surprisingly recent!), and one should be able to get asymptotics from that, but that's not obvious to someone who isn't really a combinatorialist.
2. It should be possible to define a surjective morphism $\phi:\mathbb{A}^M\to G$ over $K$ (basically because a sphere is parametrizable). How small can we take $\deg \phi$ to be, in terms of $n$? Can we make sure it is substantially smaller than $\deg(G)$?

(Assume that the characteristic of $K$ is either $0$ or non-tiny, if it helps.)

Comment: What do you mean by $\deg(G)$? Asymptotics with respect to what?

Comment: The Cayley transform gives a nice parameterization. I would be surprised to find another of lower degree.

Comment: @Sasha Its degree as an affine variety. Asymptotics as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @BenMcKay Aha. Is there something like the Cayley transform for $\textrm{Sp}_{2 n}$?

Comment: @BenMcKay Wait, the Cayley transform is not surjective, no?

Comment: I would explicitly state Theorem 4.2 of that paper into the OP, since it converts question 1 into something like a dimer model counting question that should be attackable by existing methods in statistical mechanics without requiring any knowledge of algebraic geometry.  (In particular, the answer is probably $\exp( (c+o(1)) n^2)$ for some constant $c$ that extremizes some entropy type functional.)

Comment: Isn't it easier to directly analyze the determinant in Theorem 1.1?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403787/degree-of-parametrization-of-textrmso-n#comment1034200_403787), the Cayley transform itself also provides an embedding from an open subset of $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ into $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$.  (This is just a fact about fixed points of involutions.)

Comment: @SamHopkins It's also worth stating Theorem 1.1 explicitly in the OP as well, although given that it is not immediately obvious that this determinant is positive, it may not be all that easy to obtain asymptotics for it.

Comment: It's probably best to make that into its own question, then.

Comment: Question 2 cannot be answered as written, because there is no non-constant morphism from $\mathbb{A}^n$ to $SO(2) = \{ \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} x&y \\-y&x \end{smallmatrix} \right] : x^2+y^2=1 \}$. The issue is easiest to see if there is a square root of $-1$ in $K$. In this case, $(x+\sqrt{-1} y)(x-\sqrt{-1} y)=1$ on $SO(2)$, so $x+\sqrt{-1} y$ must pull back to a unit in the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^n$, but there are no nontrivial units in $K[t_1, \ldots, t_n]$.

Comment: If $\sqrt{-1}$ is not in $K$, we can base change to $K[\sqrt{-1}]$ and then use this argument.

Comment: Regarding surjectivity of the Cayley transform: The image of the Cayley transform is those matrices for which $-1$ is not an eigenvalue; call this $U$. Every $g \in SO(n)$ is of the form $h^2$ for $h \in U$, so by composing with squaring, we can make the map surjective.